# Join between two sql statements

Tags: sql, join, union

can i join between two sql satatmnet
example

```
select ID, NAME from tab1;
12|blabla
```

and

```
Select DESC from tab2;
vvvvvv
```

I want to display to

```
12|blabla|vvvvvv
```

I was try the the UNION

```
select ID, NAME from tab1;
UNION 
Select DESC from tab2;
```

but the result was

```
12|blabla
12|vvvvv
```

any help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select ID, NAME from tab1) t1 cross join
     (Select "DESC" from tab2) t2;
```

`DESC` is a SQL reserved word, so you need to escape it.  Double quotes are one way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use UNION but instead use JOIN

Comment: Please explain why this is important. It may be obvious to you. However, you have provided an 'answer'. Please try and provide actual code that demonstrates the point you are trying to make. please explain why you think it is a useful technique. Also, please relate it to the question asked.

Comment: Also, explain *how* to accomplish this with a JOIN. Answers should actually *answer* the question, not just provide general tips and pointers in the right direction. As it is, this is a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), [not an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).